# Why Ionic cordovaCamera NOT picking videos from gallery anymore?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to pick a video from gallery in ionic / andoid using the following code, which surprisingly was working perfect in older versions of ionic

```
var  starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']); 
starter.controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {


    $scope.pickVideo = function() {

      var options = {

        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY

        };

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(videoUrl) {

      $scope.videoUrl = videoUrl;

      alert('$scope.videoUrl: '+ videoUrl);
      });

    };

  });
```

But now when I try to implement the same exact code in new ionic projects, its not working and returning empty value for videoUrl with no obvious errors.
On the other hand, it works fine for picking pictures. 
Any suggestions, alternatives or similar issues... Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same issue. 
I solved this way:

```
ionic state reset --plugins
```

Then i re added the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Then I re added the platform

```
sudo cordova platform add android
```

And started working as expected again. I had other weird issues in the past, re adding the platform in Cordova often helps